# scrollbar in dojo dialog not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, scrollbar, arcgis

I have a dialog popup box in my webapp (using the ArcGIS Javascript API w/ Dojo).  In Firefox, I get a scrollbar which functions normally, but in IE, there is a scrollabr but it doesn't work...I can arrow up/down to scroll through, but the dialog box blinks and stammers when I do this....Any suggestions? Thanks, Jason

Code:

```
    infoBox = new dijit.Dialog({
    //title: "Information",
    id: "info",
    content: infoText,
    style: "width: 450px; height: 380px; overflow: auto",
    autofocus: !dojo.isIE, // NOTE: turning focus ON in IE causes errors when  reopening the dialog
    refocus: !dojo.isIE
    //autofocus: false, // I tried this alternative, but it didn't help
    //refocus: false

    });
```

(in my setup, I have:  meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7", "IE=9" /
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
domStyle.set(infoBox.containerNode, {
    position: 'relative'
});
```

add the following code at the top --

```
require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle){ domStyle.get(node, style); domStyle.set(node, style, value); });
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried adding this code and adding 'dojo.require("dojo.dom-style")' but I get the error 'domStyle is not defined' in Firebug.  If I do not add this line, I get the same error.  (I am using v3.1 or the ArcGIS JS API). Any suggestions?

Comment: see my above comment, I also get an error "domStyle is not defined" if I do not add any require statement.

Comment: Hello, I have not yet solved this problem.  The above solution did not work for me; I get an error as stated above...anyone else have any ideas?  Can I say I hate IE?

Comment: hey Jason, Could you tell which version of dojo you are using? I'll try to investigate further...

Comment: The ArcGIS Javascript API version 3.1 uses the 1.7.3 version of Dojo.

Comment: Not sure if this works but worth a try, add the following code at the top -- 
    require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle){
    domStyle.get(node, style);
    domStyle.set(node, style, value);
    });